# I want to stop using OOP in javascript and use delegation instead

Tags: javascript, composition, delegation

After dabbling with javascript for a while, I became progressively convinced that OOP is not the right way to go, or at least, not extensively. Having two or three levels of inheritance is ok, but working full OOP like one would do in Java seems just not fitting.

The language supports compositing and delegation natively. I want to use just that. However, I am having trouble replicating certain benefits from OOP.

Namely:

1. How would I check if an object implements a certain behavior? I have thought of the following methods

   - Check if the object has a particular method. But this would mean standardizing method names and if the project is big, it can quickly become cumbersome, and lead to the java problem (object.hasMethod('emailRegexValidatorSimpleSuperLongNotConflictingMethodName')...It would just move the problem of OOP, not fix it. Furthermore, I could not find info on the performance of looking up if methods exist
   - Store each composited object in an array and check if the object contains the compositor. Something like: object.hasComposite(compositorClass)...But that's also not really elegant and is once again OOP, just not in the standard way.
   - Have each object have an "implements" array property, and leave the responsibility to the object to say if it implements a certain behavior, whether it is through composition or natively. Flexible and simple, but requires to remember a number of conventions. It is my preferred method until now, but I am still looking.
2. How would I initialize an object without repeating all the set-up for composited objects? For example, if I have an "textInput" class that uses a certain number of validators, which have to be initialized with variables, and a class "emailInput" which uses the exact same validators, it is cumbersome to repeat the code. And if the interface of the validators change, the code has to change in every class that uses them. How would I go about setting that easily? The API I am thinking of should be as simple as doing object.compositors('emailValidator','lengthValidator','...')
3. Is there any performance loss associated with having most of the functions that run in the app go through an apply()? Since I am going to be using delegation extensively, basic objects will most probably have almost no methods. All methods will be provided by the composited objects.
4. Any good resource? I have read countless posts about OOP vs delegation, and about the benefits of delegation, etc, but I can't find anything that would discuss "javascript delegation done right", in the scope of a large framework.

### edit

Further explanations:

1. I don't have code yet, I have been working on a framework in pure OOP and I am getting stuck and in need of multiple inheritance. Thus, I decided to drop classes totally. So I am now merely at theoretical level and trying to make sense out of this.
2. "Compositing" might be the wrong word; I am referring to the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), very useful for tree-like structures. It's true that it is rare to have tree structures on the front end (well, save for the DOM of course), but I am developing for node.js
3. What I mean by "switching from OOP" is that I am going to part from defining classes, using the "new" operator, and so on; I intend to use anonymous objects and extend them with delegators. Example:

   ```
   var a = {};
   compositor.addDelegates(a,["validator", "accessManager", "databaseObject"]);
   ```

So a "class" would be a function with predefined delegators:

```
  function getInputObject(type, validator){
       var input = {};
       compositor.addDelegates(input,[compositor,renderable("input"+type),"ajaxed"]);
       if(validator){input.addDelegate(validator);}
       return input;
  }
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: 2. Well, just have a Validator class which is then used by both your TextInput and EmailInput classes... I mean, when two classes need the same set of functionalities, you have to abstract that set into a separate class.

Comment: 3. If you have applies all over the place, that might mean that the structure of your application is not optimal. I would have to see the code to tell that.

Comment: By delegation you mean multi-level inheritance, right? Also, could you elaborate on compositing? I have not yet heard that term in regard to JavaScript.

Comment: Also, as I understand, inheritance (delegation) is *part of* OOP. So, you don't switch from OOP to delegation.

Comment: Yes, inheritance is a possible tool of OOP, but in no way mandatory (still most OOP centric languages utilize it). Delegation, composition ... are also OOP tools.

Comment: I edited my question to answer your concerns. I must confess I am afraid I am trying to re-invent the wheel without noticing. Not sure though. The API I am proposing makes more sense to me than classic OOP.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How would I check if an object implements a certain behavior?

Most people don't bother with testing for method existance like this.

- If you want to test for methods in order to branch and do different things if its found or not then you are probably doing something evil (this kind of `instanceof` is usually a code smell in OO code)
- If you are just checking if an object implements an interface for error checking then it is not much better then not testing and letting an exception be thrown if the method is not found. I don't know anyone that routinely does this checking but I am sure someone out there is doing it...

> 2) How would I initialize an object without repeating all the set-up for composited objects?

If you wrap the inner object construction code in a function or class then I think you can avoid most of the repetition and coupling.

> 3) Is there any performance loss associated with having most of the functions that run in the app go through an apply()?

In my experience, I prefer to avoid dealing with `this` unless strictly necessary. `this` is fiddly, breaks inside callbacks (that I use extensively for iteration and async stuff) and it is very easy to forget to set it correctly. I try to use more traditional approaches to composition. For example:

1. Having each owned object be completely independent, without needing to look at its siblings or owner. This allows me to just call its methods directly and letting it be its own `this`.
2. Giving the owned objects a reference to their owner in the form of a property or as a parameter passed to their methods. This allows the composition units to access the owner without depending on having the `this` correctly set.
3. Using mixins, flattening the separate composition units in a single level. This has big name clash issues but allows everyone to see each other and share the same "this". Mixins also decouples the code from changes in the composition structure, since different composition divisions will still flatten to the same mixed object.

> 4) Any good resources?

I don't know, so tell me if you find one :)

Comment: isn't try/catch slower than checking if a property exists? Furthermore, I might very well have two objects having a validate() method, but the methods would be completely different, so a try/catch would pass, although I would want to know if the object has the validate method that I need

Comment: The idea is that you don't even try to validate object interfaces - checking is good if it can be done at compile time but if you have to check at runtime then you might as well get a fatal error instead. Yes, getting fatal errors sucks but that is how dynamic languages roll :(